# How do I write normal Tilde(~) in C#?

Tags: c#, text

If I add a Tilde("~") in the text property of a label,the label doesn't display it,instead it displays an upper tilde.

How do I write a normal tilde like in the bracksers("~")?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Isn't that a font issue? Set the font to `Courier New` and test...

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want a fixed width font, try Unicode U223C ∼ TILDE OPERATOR rather U007E ~ TILDE